# Django won't serve static files from Amazon S3 with custom domain

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

I did setup my Django project, DNS and bucket on Amazon S3 but `python manage.py collectstatic` and therefore also files uploaded manually won't works.

**AWS S3 Settings:**

Bucket name: files.domain.com

Bucket policy:

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1483363850641",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1483363848944",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::files.domain.com/*",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

**DNS Settings:**

files.domain.com -> CNAME -> files.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com

**Django Settings:**

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XxXxXXxXXXXXxxxXxxXXXxXxxXXXXXXXXxxxXxxx'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'files.domain.com'
AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = False
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
AWS_EXPIRY = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Cache-Control': six.b('max-age=%d, s-maxage=%d, must-revalidate' % (
        AWS_EXPIRY, AWS_EXPIRY))
}

MEDIA_URL = 'http://%s/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATICFILES_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
STATIC_URL = MEDIA_URL
```

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: Sorry. Yes. ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'files.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com' doesn't match either of '*.s3.amazonaws.com', 's3.amazonaws.com'

Comment: The issue has to do with using dots on the S3 bucket name and BOTO. There is a solution but I don't have my computer with me to give you an answer but hope this let you search for the answer

Comment: Thanks @dkarchmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I included these lines on my Django settings and Amazon S3 with custom domain worked fine.

```
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = 'boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat'
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to using dots on the name. Try using:

AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat()

but I don't know if that still works as I personally just moved away from using dots on the STATICS bucket. I use a CDN anyway, so the S3 bucket name is irrelevant.

See https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2836