# Django EB using S3 storage -- collectstatic fail

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto

I've been trying to get this set up for about a week without a success so I'm desperate for some help here. I followed the tutorial on this site: https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/ to set up my django app and trying to deploy on EB but it keeps failing when it hits collectstatic command.

Here's what I have so far..

**Error Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python/current/app/manage.py", line 23, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 193, in handle
collected = self.collect()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 124, in collect
handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 337, in copy_file
if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 255, in delete_file
if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 454, in exists
return k.exists()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 539, in exists
return bool(self.bucket.lookup(self.name, headers=headers))
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 143, in lookup
return self.get_key(key_name, headers=headers)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 193, in get_key
key, resp = self._get_key_internal(key_name, headers, query_args_l)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 231, in _get_key_internal
response.status, response.reason, '')
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
```

**settings.py**

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',None)
AWS_SECRET_KEY=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_KEY',None)
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_KEY', None)
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '<my bucket name>'
AWS_S3_HOST='s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

**custom_storage.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

class StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

I tried few solutions including but not limited to: 
 - [Using Django's collectstatic with boto S3 throws "Error 32: Broken Pipe" after a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552242/using-djangos-collectstatic-with-boto-s3-throws-error-32-broken-pipe-after-a)

any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the tutorial and the fact that you're using python 3, did you installed and added django-storages-redux to your project?

Comment: Following @AlanAvalos you need django-storage-redux in your project. My question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427837/django-wont-serve-static-files-from-amazon-s3-with-custom-domain/41433454#41433454

Comment: yes I did install django-storages-redux

Comment: A while ago I did follow the same guide and the only difference with your configuration is that I didn't specify the region:
`AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`

Comment: I started with the same configuration as you did but it was failing so I changed things looking at solutions on this site..

Comment: it WORKS! thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a custom storage file and your bucket should be renamed to your custom domain, eg: **files.domain.com**

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '###############'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '###################################'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'files.domain.com'
AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = False
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = 'boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat'
AWS_S3_HOST = '<your s3 region>.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

MEDIA_URL = 'http://%s/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATICFILES_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
STATIC_URL = MEDIA_URL
```